# How to differentiate between my own types and built-in ones in questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091247/speed-of-iterating-through-drawingcollection-versus-using-contains) on stackoverflow that got me thinking. In my question I mix between describing types that I created (such as `Coordinate`, which contains information about a position in a window) and built-in types, like `DrawingGroup`. How would be the best way to, in the future, formulate my questions to make sure that someone does not mistake any of my created types with a built-in one? My first thought was to just mark them in some way, but the question became very cluttered and hard to read (harder than it already is). Is there a way to do this that I've missed, or is it such an unusual problem that it's not worth the effort?

Comment: I think this is Off-Topic here. It is more about code readability and maintainability then about SE. Think about it, if the SO community got problems with understanding your code, what will the poor guy who comes after you do? All in all, I wouldn't worry about it too much. Normally the specific community members know their languages, frameworks and environments good enough to know what is a built-in type and what not. On the other hand, it never hurts to explain shortly where all those types come from, but do not compromise the code samples.

Comment: @Asylum yeah, when you put it that way I see how you're probably right. My thought process was something along the lines that people that read the code after/with me should probably have a bigger knowledge of the codebase and if not, an easier time to figure it out than someone on SO. But I guess I'll just have to put my trust in the hands of my fellow SO-nians :)

Comment: Actually, I think it would be quite useful to have a markup option to distinguish builtins from custom datatypes or classes. For example, there's lots of times when all that makes a classname unique is a namespace.

Comment: @PhilLello: If a type/name is ambiguous, it should be clearly stated/explained in the question/code where that type comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone competent in that area of development that intends to answer your question will likely recognise the types - but the easiest way might be to link to the online documentation for "built-in" types the first time you reference them.

Often giving the shortest possible listing of concerned custom types is useful and will serve to differentiate too. But sometimes that's not possible or ideal, and the question is a little long already.

Comment: As you said, the question I linked to was pretty long anyway. In future questions I'll probably do a short listing of (if any) custom types. Thanks for the answer!